# Read in all the files in a particular directory displays the file names in a html list

Tags: php

Reading all the files from a particular directory and  displays the files names/Links in a html list.
(file ext: .pdf)
I'm looking for output something like:

- filename 1
- filename 2
- filename 3

My code:

```
<ul> 
    <?php 
      $dir = '/my_directory_location'; 
      $files = scandir($dir); 
      foreach ($files as $ind_file) { 
      ?> <li> <a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></li> 
      <?php } ?> 
</ul>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Great, what's your questions?  What have you tried?  This isn't some place where you hire folks to write code for you, this is where you come to learn.  It's hard to help you learn when we don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted my code.
Here it is :
//------------

<ul> 
<?php 
$dir = '/my_directory_location'; 
$files = scandir($dir); 
foreach($files as $ind_file){ 
?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></li> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</ul> 
//-----------

Comment: Can you edit your question and post that?  That would be helpful.  Otherwise, we might be missing something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) in PHP

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
resume1.pdf
resume4.pdf
resume5.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$ARR_FILES = glob($PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY."/*.pdf");
foreach($ARR_FILES as $filename)
{
  echo $filename."<br/>";
}
```